# Mod_wsgi configure with wamp

Tags: windows, apache, python-2.7, wamp, mod-wsgi

I am using Windows XP(32 bit),Wamp 2.2 Apache 2.2.22 and Python 2.7

I am trying to setup a WAMPServer and am stuck on which file I need to download from the site: http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#mod_wsgi

Also, many of the tutorials I have seen on the matter say to download a .so file. However the above link contains .whl files?

if someone help me.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Go to the mod_wsgi documentation and read it instead:

- https://github.com/GrahamDumpleton/mod_wsgi/blob/develop/win32/README.rst

Once the module is loaded into Apache, then for setting up the WSGI application see:

- https://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/QuickConfigurationGuide

Comment: i download mod_wsgi.so file and enable it, But my pythan port not available how to enable